# Background Threads not closing when root node is changed [javaFX]

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, nfc

I am creating a javafx program and my navigation menu for the program works by changing the root of the scene. The roots all inherit from the Pane class. Some of the Panes have background threads which they run. But when the the root pane is changed by the event handlers the Pane switches but the background threads to not stop. Which causes problems as the threads read NFC and results in multiple threads trying to read from the NFC reader.
How can I close the the background threads ? (from outside the pane where they are created) or do I need to set up the threads in a different manner.
(The threads are set to Daemon).
The threads are created in the Pane constructor like so: 
(I had assumed since they belonged to the Pane when the pane is switched the thread will stop. That is not the case).

```
  Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
         public void run () {
             boolean cont = true;
             while(cont){

                try {
                    NFCcard create1 = new NFCcard();

                    String staffID=create1.getCardID().toString();
                    staffID = staffID.replaceAll("\\D+","");
                    signIn.setText("Welcome "+getUserName(staffID)+getPhotoSrc(create1.getCardID().toString()));

                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (CardException e) {


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                signIn.setText("Scan your card to sign in/out");
                if(getScene().getRoot().isDisable());
                    cont=false;
             }

            }};

     Thread nfcCheckThread = new Thread(r);
     nfcCheckThread.setDaemon(true);
     nfcCheckThread.start();
```

I switch Panes in a static way like this: ( this methods are within there own class).

```
   public static void homeButtonhandler(Stage stage){ 
     HomePane mainPane1=new HomePane(stage, new HomeContent(stage));
     stage.getScene().setRoot(mainPane1);
     }
 public static void adminButtonhandler(Stage stage){

      DialogBox dialog = new  DialogBox();

      try{
        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.get().equals("115")){
            AdminPane adminPane1 = new AdminPane(stage,new Content(stage));
            stage.getScene().setRoot(adminPane1);
            }}

        catch(NoSuchElementException Exception){

        }


 }

public static void workingTodayButtonhandler(Stage stage){
     //TODO trying to make the content change when when buttons are clicked

     HomePane mainPane2=new HomePane(stage,new WorkingTodayContent(stage));

     stage.getScene().setRoot(mainPane2); 
//  System.out.println(mainPane2.content);

 }
```

First calling is:

HomePane myPane = new HomePane(primaryStage,new HomeContent(primaryStage));

```
    Scene homeScene = new Scene (myPane);

    primaryStage.setMinHeight(1000);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(1700);

    primaryStage.setScene(homeScene);


    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Daemon threads exit when the jvm exits or main returns. If you want to exit earlier you need to close them manually. The standard way of doing that is to have the backround threads regularly check a "keepGoing" flag, which you can unset when you want them to exit.

Comment: The threads being deamon threads does not have any effect except not preventing shutdown of the runtime. You need to implement some logic for shutting down those threads yourself... Probably you could use some `AtomicReference` updated from a listener to the `Scene` root that allows the `Thread`s to check, if the root of the scene is still "their" root and terminate otherwise, but it's hard to recommend anything, since the amount of information about your design is small... Using executor services could help btw...

Comment: If you do not show how the threads are being created and closed in your code, we cannot say if you need to set up the threads in a different manner or not! Please provide some [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates your situation.

Comment: What should it check to see if it should keep going I tried using: if(getScene().getRoot().isDisable()); But it didn't work.

Comment: Where is it you define your first code sample gets called?? And is HomePane a self-made class??

Comment: I made homePane it is a pane made up of other self made panes.First call has been added above.

Comment: I meant where (in which class, which method) do you create the runnable and the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said:

> Some of the Panes have background threads which they run.

I'll suppose you create these threads in your own `Pane` implementations. I'll show you a solution with an abstract class that each of your panes (or at least the ones that you insert as a root) should extend. If you do not have that, I strongly recommend you to do so. You didn't provide much information about those panes though, so I'll leave you the task of integrating my answer in your code(if ever you decide to follow it).

```
public abstract class OwnPane extends Pane {
    protected volatile boolean isRoot = false;

    public void setAsRoot(){
        isRoot = true;
    }

    public void unsetAsRoot(){
        isRoot = false;
    }
}
```

I will come backt to the `volatile` keyword later.

Now you can create your thread, preferably in `OwnPane` or a subclass of it, in a `activateThread`-method for example:

```
public void activateNFCThread(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run () {
                 while(isRoot){
                      // what the thread has to do ...
                 }
            }
    };
    Thread nfcCheckThread = new Thread(r);
    nfcCheckThread.setDaemon(true);
    nfcCheckThread.start();
}
```

Now I can explain why the `volatile` keyword has to be used: the field `isRoot` will be used by different threads. With the `volatile` keyword we make sure all threads will access the same "variable" (else each thread will have its own version for performance reasons).
The fact that the thread gets created in a method in `OwnPane` (or a subclass), allows to access the `isRoot` field from within the `Runnable` object. In subclasses of `OwnPane` you can then even override the `setAsRoot` method to make the NFS thread start directly when the `setAsRoot` method gets called (if needed):

```
public class PaneWithNFCReader extends OwnPane {
    @Override
    public void setAsRoot(){
         super.setAsRoot();
         activateNFCThread();
    }
}
```

Finally you can use these methods to change the root pane of a scene in a stage:

```
// All your methods regarding stage changes are static, so I'll leave this one static too
public static void changeRoot(Stage stage, OwnPane newRoot){
    OwnPane oldStage = (OwnPane)stage.getScene().getRoot();
    oldStage.unsetAsRoot();
    Platform.runLater(() -> {   //Platform.runLater to be sure the main thread that will execute this 
                                //(only main thread is allowed to change something in the JavaFX nodes)
        stage.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
        newRoot.setAsRoot();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a way to register a listener to the class responsible for replacing the scene root. This allows you to be notified of such changes and react by making the threads terminate.

**Example**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface NodeReplaceListener {

    public void onNodeReplace();

}
```

```
private Parent root;
private NodeReplaceListener listener;
private Scene scene;

public void setRoot(Parent root, NodeReplaceListener listener) {
    if (root != this.root && this.listener != null) {
        this.listener.onNodeReplace();
    }
    this.root = root;
    this.listener = listener;

    scene.setRoot(root);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Next Scene");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        // replace root
        setRoot(new StackPane(new Rectangle(100, 100)), null);
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    scene = new Scene(new Group(), 100, 100);

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        // running volatile to guarantee that visibility of written values to all threads
        volatile boolean running = true;

        int i;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                System.out.println(i++);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            running = false;
        }

    }

    MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // cancel runnable when root is replaced
    setRoot(root, r::cancel);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

BTW: Note that modifications to the scene should not be made from any thread but the application thread. Use `Platform.runLater` for updates from a different thread:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> signIn.setText("Scan your card to sign in/out"));
```